# How to show opened windows in the panel seperately on multiple monitors?

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, xubuntu, xfce-panel

As mentioned in the title, how to show opened windows in the panel seperately on multiple monitors?

**Illustration:**

I have 2 screens.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Let's say I have Firefox opened in screen 1, and Chrome opened in screen 2, I would like the screen 1 panel to show Firefox ONLY, and screen 2 panel to show Chrome ONLY. However, what I got is this:

[image]

Any panels I add will just include every windows opened regardless of which screen they're in. Any way to solve this? or is it even possible?

Some info of my system:

- OS : Ubuntu 11.10
- Desktop environment : Xubuntu (because I'm familiar with Ubuntu 10.04)
- Graphic card : VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07).

I have another laptop which is running Ubuntu 10.04LTS, where this work automatically after I setup the `System>Administrator>NVIDIA X Server Settings`.

```
junrong@junrong-Studio-1537:~$ xdpyinfo | grep -C 2 dimensions

screen #0:
  dimensions:    2560x1024 pixels (676x270 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your displays may be using Xinerama (or not? twinview etc) so the window manager may not be aware that it is dealing with 2 screens and sees it as one large display. 
Please post `xdpyinfo | grep -C 2 dimensions`xdpyinfo | grep -C 2 dimensions

Edit: ok, as I expected, your X11 server is exposing just one large virtual screen which merges your two physical screens into one. It may not be possible to do what you want with the intel driver, I don't know.

1. Option 1: Create your own xorg.conf file with xinerama rather than whatever the intel driver is doing. (start with `Xorg -configure` and look online for xinerama setups)
2. Option 2: spend $20 on a cheap PCIe graphics card (assuming this is not a laptop obviously) and it will probably just work straight away as the drivers won't merge the screens driven by separate cards.

Comment: thanks, I placed the requested info as an update in the question, do you have any further advice?